# Custom Text-To-Speech Narrator voices for Windows Screen Reader

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11, text-to-speech, screen-reader

I've been messing around a bit with TorToiSe TTS a bit recently and have realized that Windows 11 has a built-in screen reader function for people with vision impairment. I was wondering if there was any way to create a custom TTS voice, similar to a voice clone from TorToiSe, for screen reading on Windows that outputs something somewhat natural, like the default "natural" voices built into Windows? Where would I start with creating something like that, and how would I be able to use it in Windows by default?